# measure the time taken by the reports embedded in a webpage using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

how to measure the time taken by the reports to display data embedded in an iframe of webpage?

I have used time.sleep() function earlier. but i have to record the report loading time.

```
browser.get('https://public.tableau.com/profile/ifpri.td7290#!/vizhome/2014GHI/2014GHI')
browser.get('https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/books-made-movies?gallery=votd')
```

Comment: based on your answer i got to know that i have to use selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions. is it correct? in my urls you could see there is an iframe and it will load the data into report with some delay.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how the hole code looks but if you begin with `from time import sleep` theres no need to begin with `time.sleep()`.

Comment: here is my code. if you look at the URL's there is an iframe that holds the report. one spinner appears before report show the data. how to measue that time?
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):


        browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chrome Driver\chromedriver')
        try:
            browser.get('https://public.tableau.com/profile/ifpri.td7290#!/vizhome/2014GHI/2014GHI')
            browser.get('https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery/books-made-movies?gallery=votd')
        finally:
            print(time.ctime() + "Quit")

        time.sleep(1)

Answer (score -2):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")`
```

Comment: It was my first comment. Sorry for the mumbo-jumbo syntax

Comment: `enter code here` is unnecessary

Comment: and turns out I cant edit my answer

Comment: i am looking on how to measure the time taken by report to show the data